# AngularFire update single object

Tags: firebase, angularfire

How to update a single object within node.

```
{ 
 foo: 
  {
   title: 'hello world', 
   time: '1000'
  } 
}
```

As above, I just want update title.
`$firebase(new Firebase(ref).child('foo')).$save();` will update the entire node. Also tried `$save('title')` but not work.

The reason I just want to update a single object, because some of the ng-model doesn't need to update to `firebase`.

Comment: Can you please include enough code that we could reproduce your error? $save works as expected when I utilize it, so we'll need to see your specific use case.

Answer (score 3):

Heres an example setting the title to "whatever"

```
$firebase(new Firebase(ref)).$child('foo').$child('title').$set("whatever")
```

Comment: I suspect you need another ) in here somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I have recently been working with angularfire and firebase. I am not sure if this is a fix but i dont think you dont need to explicitly select the item property you want to update when you are using the $save() method.

For instance, in my use case i was selecting a user and had an init function that got that whole object

**html**

```
<ul ng-repeat="user in vm.users>
    <button ng-click="vm.updateUserInit(user)">Edit</button>
</ul>
```

This then opened up the update form with the users properties. In the controller i took that user and assigned it into a `$firebaseObject`.

**controller**

```
var selectedUser;

vm.updateUserInit = function (user) {
        var ref = new Firebase("https://<foo>.firebaseio.com/users/" + user.$id);
        selectedUser = $firebaseObject(ref);
}
```

It justs puts the user into a firebase object as the variable `selectedUser` to use in the $save.

Then when the user updates the details

**html**

```
<button type="button" ng-click="vm.updateUserDetails()">Update User Details</button>
```

the function already has the selected user as an object to use and anything added will be updated. Anything omitted will not.

**controller**

```
vm.updateUserDetails = function () {
   selectedUser.firstName = vm.firstName;
   selectedUser.$save();
 }
```

The `selectedUser.$save();` changes only the first name even though the user has 6 other properties

Not sure if this helps, trying to wrap my head around all of this as well. Check out [valcon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vulcan-by-firebase/oippbnlmebalopjbkemajgfbglcjhnbl?hl=en) if you dont already have it. Really nice extension on the chrome inspector for firebase

**UPDATE FOR ANGULARFIRE 2**

if you create a service for your calls , which could serve all update calls

```
 constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}

 update(fbPath: string, data: any) {
     return this.db.object(fbPath).update(data);
 }
```

And then in the page component

```
 this.api.update(`foo`, ({ title: 'foo Title' }) );
```

Much simpler